Ray logging is not working for logging.info calls in main or worker process
I am trying to set up a logger on Windows that can output messages to both a log file as well as stdout with different log levels.  I am using ray to run a couple of remote worker processes so I would like the settings to apply to those as well as any logging calls in the main process.
I have set this up as a test below but I am only getting the ray logged messages in the file and stdout.  Neither of my logging calls in the main or the remote process are getting logged.
def setup_logging():
    # Change root logger level from WARNING (default) to NOTSET in order for all messages to be delegated.
    logging.getLogger("ray").setLevel(logging.NOTSET)

    # Add stdout handler
    console = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    console.setFormatter(formatter)
    
    logging.getLogger("ray").addHandler(console)

    # Add file handler
    curDate = dt.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    if os.path.isdir('logs') == False:
        os.mkdir('logs')

    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(f'logs/factor_regime-{curDate}.log')
    fileHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    
    logging.getLogger("ray").addHandler(fileHandler)
    
@ray.remote
def worker_process():
    logging.info("This is a worker process log message.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # setup logging
    setup_logging()

    # setup logging for ray
    ray.init(runtime_env={"worker_process_setup_hook": setup_logging})

    logging.debug("Testing logging")

    ray.get([worker_process.remote()])

The only logged message I get is:
    2024-06-12 10:14:42 - INFO - Started a local Ray instance. View the dashboard at [1m[32mhttp://127.0.0.1:8265 [39m[22m

If I change logging.getLogger("ray") to logging.getLogger() in the setup_logger function the ray log message is posted to stdout and both of my log messages appear where I expect them.  But during the ray initialization ray acquires a lock on the log file and then releases it again and does that about 10 times before continuing as follows:.
DEBUG - Attempting to acquire lock 1806647119952 on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\node_ip_address.json.lock
DEBUG - Lock 1806647119952 acquired on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\node_ip_address.json.lock
DEBUG - Attempting to release lock 1806647119952 on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\node_ip_address.json.lock
DEBUG - Lock 1806647119952 released on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\node_ip_address.json.lock
DEBUG - Attempting to acquire lock 1806647128336 on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Lock 1806647128336 acquired on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Attempting to release lock 1806647128336 on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Lock 1806647128336 released on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Attempting to acquire lock 1806647129360 on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Lock 1806647129360 acquired on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Attempting to release lock 1806647129360 on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Lock 1806647129360 released on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Attempting to acquire lock 1806647129232 on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Lock 1806647129232 acquired on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Attempting to release lock 1806647129232 on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Lock 1806647129232 released on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Attempting to acquire lock 1806647128784 on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Lock 1806647128784 acquired on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Attempting to release lock 1806647128784 on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Lock 1806647128784 released on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Attempting to acquire lock 1806647129744 on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Lock 1806647129744 acquired on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Attempting to release lock 1806647129744 on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
DEBUG - Lock 1806647129744 released on C:\Users\nbell\AppData\Local\Temp\ray\session_2024-06-12_11-29-00_960725_49628\ports_by_node.json.lock
2024-06-12 11:29:06,252 INFO worker.py:1740 -- Started a local Ray instance. View the dashboard at http://127.0.0.1:8265

Which method is the most appropriate method and how do I get it to do what I want?
